# excel vba saveasui file path

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a template for registration of changes. These are the requests and further administration in the process. I have a code in this template to save the file as an excel macro enabled workbook, always. The problem with this code is that i can't define a specific folder to save the documents. In all cases the save as dialog box will pop up and the user must be able to define their own file name. I want to define the path for all the users. Does anyone know how to add a file location (path) in this macro in order to make it work?

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim FileNameVal As String
If SaveAsUI Then
    FileNameVal = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    Cancel = True
    If FileNameVal = "False" Then 'User pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Right(ThisWorkbook.Name, 5) <> ".xlsm" Then
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameVal, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameVal, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Remco H.

Comment: If you want to force them to use your path, and only allow them to give a filename, why use the `GetSaveAsFilename` dialog at all - just use an `InputBox` and ask them to supply the filename (and then prepend your fixed path to whatever they give)?  Or, if you want to use `GetSaveAsFilename` so that they can click an existing filename rather than typing it in, you could either strip off the path portion of `FileNameVal` and put your own path in, or you could make the user keep choosing filenames until the path matches your required path.

Comment: The filename i am using is yymmdd-followup as in 161214-1, 14th of december 2016 with follow up number 1. With the save as dialog they always have to check the available follow up number in the specific folder. It's not possible to define the correct name without checking the folder. So what i have now is the save as box popping up and the document is set to macro enabled workbook. I only need the path specified. Or is it possible to create the filename automatically with the right follow up number (checking the folder). In that case, i can work with that. But i might need some help or tips..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to generate a unique filename, you could use something like the following function:

```
Function NextFileName(basename As String) As String
    Dim followup As Integer
    Dim pathname As String
    pathname = "C:\Temp\Temp\" ' Include the trailing path separator so that we don't have to do it later
    followup = 1
    Do
        NextFileName = pathname & basename & "-" & followup & ".xlsm"
        If Dir(NextFileName) = "" Then Exit Function
        followup = followup + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

You could then call it from your main code as

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim FileNameVal As String
    If SaveAsUI Then  ' <-- Exclude the IF statement if you want EVERY save to have a new follow up number
                      '     rather than just "Save As" saves
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Generate the filename
        FileNameVal = NextFileName(Format(Now, "yymmdd"))
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameVal, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        'Maybe advise the user that the save has happened, and where it went to
        MsgBox "Spreadsheet saved as " & FileNameVal
        Cancel = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is almost working flawless. When i press save in the document, i still have to click a random map (folder). After selecting the random map, it automatically generates the specific filename with the follow up in the correct folder.

Comment: @RemcoH. - Don't show the dialog, just save the file where you want it to go.  (See edit)

Comment: This created another problem. Saving the file will generate a new number automatically. For example, i edited document 161214-3 and im trying to save it, it will automatically create a new number (161214-4). The template has to create new numbers, but editing an existing document should not change the name after saving. So close!

Comment: @RemcoH. After my previously mentioned edit, I edited it again soon after to put the `If SaveAsUI Then` back in (with a comment to get rid of the `If` if you wanted it to generate a new number every time).  Check to make sure you are looking at the latest edit.  So for my testing it ended up updating the number if I did a "Save As" but left the number unchanged with a "Save".